# How to receive AJAX type post with PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I have got this straightforward HTML form

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="Mesform">
    <textarea maxlength="400" type="text" placeholder="Your message" class="MessageInp"></textarea>
    <div class="attach">
    <input type="file" id="chatfil" accept="image/*">
    <label for="chatfil">
        <img src="../img/camera.png" class="addphc">
    </label>
</form>
```

and this jquery

```
$("body").delegate('.MessageInp','keydown',function(e) {
    if (e.which==13 ) {
        $(".Mesform").submit();
    }
});
```

That's how i submit my form

```
$(".Mesform").submit(function(){
    var val=$(this).children('textarea').val();
    var who=$(".headChat").text();
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    alert(formData);
        if (val!="") {
            $.ajax({
                url: '../files/ajax.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data:formData,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data)
                },
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false
            });
        }
    return false;                   
});
```

But I do not know how to receive this AJAX call with PHP

Comment: fyi: `<textarea>` does not have a type.

Comment: It is just like submitting a form. The data will be in the `$_POST` array. You probably do not want to use `async: false` in your AJAX request as it will lock up your browser until the request completes.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks.i forgot to change.

Comment: @JayBlanchard so i should get $_POST[]with that inside?

Comment: [Yep, you should.](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: @JayBlanchard it is a question :D

Comment: In `../files/ajax.php` add `print_r($_POST);` as the very first line and you should see the POST array.

Comment: if the ultimate goal is to upload files with ajax, have a look at this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23980733/jquery-ajax-file-upload-php

Comment: there is no "ajax-type post". there's just http post requests, and they all show up at the server the same way. php doesn't care if it was a ajax call or someone clicking `submit` in a form.

Comment: @Fred-ii- what about text area?

Comment: @JayBlanchard 's tutorial link should help.

Comment: @JayBlanchard it returns Array()

Comment: What is the code for `../files/ajax.php`? How are you populating `$(this)[0]`?

Comment: @JayBlanchard It sends data to that file.Which gets that and i added `print_r($_POST); ` as you advised and it returns Array()

Comment: You're not understanding what I am saying. How are you calling your AJAX request?

Comment: When user clicks enter on textarea i submit form through jquery and this ajax thing is in  `$(".Mesform").submit(function(){`

Comment: Show us all of the code.

Comment: I added the whole jquery @JayBlanchard

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: @JayBlanchard  This is my localhost.Yes other ajax calls that i send with GET work.

Comment: Have you confirmed `formData` contains what you expect?

Comment: i did `alert(formData);` which returned [object FormData]

Comment: You need to give all of your inputs and the textarea name attributes and they'll show up in the POST or FILE array.

Comment: Please, [quit using `alert()` for troubleshooting.](http://stravid.com/en/stop-the-javascript-alert-madness/), use `console.log()` instead.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Yes it worked.i added name to textarea and in php i did        `if(isset($_POST['textarea'])){`

Comment: @JayBlanchard are you going to post the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the form elements to show up in any request array, such as `$_POST` they will need name attributes (`name="<something>"`). For example:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="Mesform">
    <textarea name="description" maxlength="400" placeholder="Your message" class="MessageInp"></textarea>
    <div class="attach">
    <input name="chatfil" type="file" id="chatfil" accept="image/*">
    <label for="chatfil">
        <img src="../img/camera.png" class="addphc">
    </label>
</form>
```

Plus as stated, `<textarea>` does not use a type.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments and answer.I learned a lot from you :D

Comment: Glad to help @COp!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is this way:

```
switch (strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'])) {
    case 'post':
        $postdata = file_get_contents('php://input'));
        //Do Something For Post
        break;
    case 'get':
        $getdata = file_get_contents('php://input'));
        //Do Something For Get
        break;
}
```

Comment: fyI: switch/case requires "break". edit: ah you added it now

Comment: I am sure there far more less complicated ways.If i had enough reputation i would downvote too

Comment: @COp "I am sure there far more less complicated ways." So you would downvote based on your assumption that something exists?

Comment: It is not assumption.

Comment: Sure.I did not mean to offend you in any. @Aaron

Comment: @COp I'm not offended, I just want to believe what you are saying.

Comment: The less complicated way, since the AJAX request is made as `type: 'POST'` is to read the `$_POST` array. In addition, the addition of `file_get_contents()` adds an unnecessary layer of complexity to a simple AJAX request.

Comment: @JayBlanchard That's not less complicated: For example, If the content-type is `application/json` the `$_POST` method will not work because the `$_POST` wrapper does not know how to handle it. Less complicated is subjective here. The original poster gets a pass here, but if he wishes to send JSON, your method will not work.

Comment: Wait....whut? You can't put JSON in a `$_POST` array variable? Golly, I'm going to have to go back and change hundreds of AJAX requests.

Comment: It is a simple AJAX request using the POST method. How else do you expect to send form variables to a PHP page for processing? That is what the OP is asking for.

Comment: @JayBlanchard What you're saying is true, but the OP doesn't need JQuery for that.

Comment: No, but he has chosen to use it.

Comment: @JayBlanchard And That's why my answer is also valid.

Comment: Well, it would be valid if it contained an explanation of why you use the code.